# SQL Server IF ELSE select random item from count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a webshop and I can't find the correct way of using just 1 query in order to bring up 4 similar random products based on their shared category. There are 3 levels of categories for each product.

Columns in products that I need to check for are `product_id`, `category_class_1`, `category_class_2`, `category_class_3`.

I want to do an if elseif elseif else type of condition where I bring 4 products that have the same `category_class_3`, if it's less than 4 bring the rest from the same `category_class_2`, if it's less than 4 bring the rest from `category_class_3`, if less than 4 bring any random product.

I'm currently doing this with a switch in my service and I'd like to know if this will actually have benefit to use just 1 query, currently having 4 queries, if it's the worse case scenario.

EDIT: The expression (ABS(CAST((BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) * RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 10 will return a number from 1 to 99. RAND() will give a float between 0 and 1, BINARY_CHECKSUM gives an integer number based on what you call it for. CAST will return a variable to as the type you choose (int in this case). To which you do modulo and compare.

For my query I've used NEWID() as this is SQL Server way of getting a random row.

```
select 
top 4
    product_id,
    class1, 
    class2, 
    class3
from 
(
select 
    product_id,
    class1, 
    class2, 
    class3,
    level=1
from products 
where  
  class3=@class3_value
  and product_id<>@product_id
    UNION 
select 
    product_id,
    class1, 
    class2, 
    class3,
    level=2
from products 
where  
  class2=@class2_value
  and product_id<>@product_id
    UNION
select 
    product_id,
    class1, 
    class2, 
    class3,
    level=3
from products 
where  
  class1=@class1_value
  and product_id<>@product_id
 ) T
order by NEWID()
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far? With some code and some data.

Comment: You're looking for a `CASE` statement. I'm only partially following your logic, can you show some table/data examples, what you have tried and desired results?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't post any queries, it's a multitude of where clauses like this one:

$switchSelect = $adapter->select()
                        ->from(array(self::TABLE_NAME), array('id' => 'product_id'))
                        ->where('product_id <> ?', $productId)
                        ->where('class2 = ?', $levelTwo)
                        ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))
                        ->limit(4);
                    $similarProducts = $adapter->fetchAssoc($switchSelect); for each switch case.

I'm still new to Zend and this complex expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a query like below. Assumption is that your current product_id is category information is available as parameters to query

```
select 
     TOP 4
        product_id,
        category_class_1, 
        category_class_2, 
        category_class_3
    from 
    (
    select 
        product_id,
        category_class_1, 
        category_class_2, 
        category_class_3,
        level=1
    from products 
    where  
      category_class_3=@Category_class_3
      and product_id<>@product_id
      and (ABS(CAST(
      (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) *
      RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 100

        UNION 

    select 
        product_id,
        category_class_1, 
        category_class_2, 
        category_class_3,
        level=2
    from products 
    where  
      category_class_2=@Category_class_2
      and product_id<>@product_id
      and (ABS(CAST(
      (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) *
      RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 100

        UNION

    select 
        product_id,
        category_class_1, 
        category_class_2, 
        category_class_3,
        level=3
    from products 
    where  
      category_class_1=@Category_class_1
      and product_id<>@product_id
      and (ABS(CAST(
      (BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) *
      RAND()) as int)) % 100) < 100
    )T
    order by T.level asc
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply DhruvJoshi. It's working flawlessly.

Comment: Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Comment: Well problem is it always selects the same 4 products.
abs(cast(BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) * RAND() AS int)) % 100 will always return a value less than 100. I didn't know what BINARY_CHECKSUM and ABS are used for at first when I posted my first reply.

Comment: you can change the value from <100 to <10

Comment: You were of great help. Thanks again.